# Python Scraping Problem with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using python I am trying to get the whole html code of a target CSS selector. The target html code looks like following and I want this whole code:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="/svg/2798804.svg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="kitten animal cat " style="user-select: auto;">
```

My python code :

```
with open("links.txt", "r") as a_file:
  for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    endpoint = stripped_line
    start = stripped_line.find('/tag/') + 5
    end = stripped_line.find('.html', start)
    filename = stripped_line[start:end]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(endpoint).text)
    completeName = os.path.join(workingpath, filename + ".txt")
    with open(completeName, "w") as f_out:
        for inp in soup.select('.card-img-top'):
            print(inp["value"], file=f_out)
```

Getting this error when running the code:

```
KeyError: 'value'
```

Comment: Do you expect the `<img>` to be an `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with BeautifulSoup. `value` attribute does not exist in your html fragment (because `img` has no such attribute, but `input` has it as suggested by @KlausD.)

```
>>> inp.attrs
{'class': ['card-img-top'],
 'src': '/svg/2798804.svg',
 'width': '200px',
 'height': '200px',
 'alt': 'kitten animal cat ',
 'style': 'user-select: auto;'}
```

All possible attributes for `img` tag can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

Comment: Thanks @corralien I am fairly new in this field. Now it is working fine. But I need to get the 'src' and 'alt' at the same time. Then save to a text file line by line. Can you help me with that. As I said I am new and tried a few ideas but failed.

Comment: Succeeded with this "print(inp.attrs["src"], inp.attrs["alt"], sep="\n", file=f_out)"